# Stacking numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create multiple rows of three arrays and then stack them vertically so that I would have 16 rows of array a above 16 of b above 56 of c.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.tile([25.5395,1.98040,20.2861,0.143384,11.9812,9.34972,4.50073,19.5810,0.689690],(16,1))
b=np.tile([19.5114,0.178847,8.23473,6.67018,2.01341,-0.29263,1.52080,12.9464,-13.280],(16,1))
c=np.tile([3.04850,13,2771,2.28680,5.70110,1.54639,0.323900,0.867000,32.9089,0.250800],(56,1))
d=np.vstack((a,b))
e=np.vstack((d,c))
```

The above code gives the error

```
'ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly'.
```

The error comes from the `np.vstack` line. Whilst I assume the error is self-explanatory as far as I can see the arrays do have the same dimensions along the non-concatenated axis as they each have length 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` has a length of 10.

Is the second element in `c` supposed to be `13.2771` instead of `13, 2771`? 
(I assume so because then it would match the number of sig figs as the rest of the values). If so, then `a`, `b`, and `c` would all have length of 9.